# Getting values correctly while using Many to Many relation

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I have standart User model and Categories model like this;

```
class Categories(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And here is another class for relation which associates some users with some categories;

```
class Interested(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Categories)
```

For example if I have Users such as Bob, Eric, Oliver, Michael

and categories such as Basketball, Football

and relations like that

- Bob -> Basketball,Football
- Eric-> Basketball
- Oliver -> Football

(michael not interested in anything)

I want to get list of who interested in what? How can I handle this? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the instance of Interested for a user with:

```
interested = Interested.objects.get(user="your user")
```

and list the linked categorys by:

```
interested.category.all()
```

But I would, if not nescessary for any other reason, just link the category directly to the user....

```
class Category(models.Model):
   name = models.Charfield()
   user = models.ManyToManyField(user)
```

This way you can get the categorys for a user:

`categorys = Category.objects.filter(user="youruser")`

and if you pass this to your template just do:

`{% for category in categorys %} {{ category.name }}{% endfor %}`

To get the users interested in a category, just get the Category instance with:

`category = Category.objects.get(name="categoryname")`

and the the related user models with:

`usersincategory = category.user.all()`

if you want this for all categorys just use a normal for loop:

`categorys = Category.objects.all()
for category in categorys:
   category.user.all()`

Comment: Thank you for reply. How can i get list of distinct user who is interested in any category?

Comment: Edited my awnser... If you want to use your Interested model at all costs, change one of the manytomany fields to foreignkey and acces it via the foreign key related model instance...